# How do I iterate over a list inside an observable?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm still pretty much a beginner when it comes to Angular and spent the last few days looking for a solution. I'm accessing an API that returns pages of JSON results in the following format:
`{"count": 242, "next": <link to the next page>, "results":[]}`

My get function looks like this:

```
getJournals(searchterm, limit?: number, offset?: number): Observable<any> {
    var endpointurl = this.globalvars.apiv1Url + "search-journal?q=" + searchterm;
    if (limit != null) {
        endpointurl = endpointurl + "&limit=" + limit;
    }
    if (offset != null) {
        endpointurl = endpointurl + "&offset=" + offset;
    }
    return this.http.get(endpointurl).pipe(map((res: Response) => this.extractJournals(res)));
}
```

The extract function processes the results and hands them over to a factory so I get journal objects that fit my datamodel.

```
private extractJournals(res: Response) {
    let body: any = { count: res["count"], next: res["next"], journals: [] };
    if (body["count"] > 0) {
        for (var index = 0; index < res["results"].length; ++index) {
            var journalInfo: any = res["results"][index];
            this.journalFactory.create(journalInfo, body.journals);
        }
    }

    return body || {};
}
```

The second parameter of the create function is optional and accepts a list to push results back into.
Now for the problematic part. The page that calls getJournals (the journal declaration fits the journals into an ngx-datatable):

```
getJournals(limit: number, offset: number) {
    this.page.limit = limit;
    this.page.offset = offset;
    this.api.getJournals("", limit, offset).subscribe((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        this.page.count = result["count"];
        if (result["count"] > 0) {
            console.log(result["journals"].length);
            result["journals"].forEach((currentjournal) => {
                console.log(currentjournal);
                var journal: any = {};

                this.rows.push(journal);
            });
            this.rows = [...this.rows];
        }
    });
}
```

The first console log returns what I would expect. I know it's an observable and returns not what was inside it at the moment it was logged but gets evaluated as I click on it in the browser. The log contains all my journals in the form I want and everything is fine. The second log returns '0' and the third gets never called.
From what I understand the iteration would work if my observable itself returned a list but it doesn't because I want to iterate over a list that's nested in the result(?). What's also interesting is that result["count"] returns the right result from the API at any time and it gets filled in the extractJournals function. I think that means extractJournals filled the body variable but doesn't wait for the for loop before it returns a result? But it does process the for loop at SOME point because the first log contains the for loop results.

I'm really out of ideas. How do I get this last forEach loop to work since it apparently doesn't wait for the journals list to be filled? I also tried a regular for loop with index btw.

Comment: What version of angular are you using and what http service are you using? If it's `HttpClient` it should be returning an Object not a Response.

Comment: @shusson I'm using `HttpClient` and Angular 7. I have now replaced `res:Response`  with `data` but I'm getting the same result. Btw I'm getting no error messages anywhere.

Comment: it won't change the result but it will help you navigate your result. I would suggest you create an interface in typescript that describes your data that should help you parse it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make advantage of the fact that typescript transpiler can point you where there is a typo in your code. For example:

```js
let body: {count: number, next: string, journals: Journal[]} = {"count": res["count"], "next": res["next"], "journals": []};


this.journalFactory.create(journalInfo, body.journals);
                                             // ^^^ Please notice typo here
```

Almost every IDE and transpilation process will throw an error when you give a type information to the typescript.

Comment: the typo happened while editing the code for StackOverflow and removing some clutter. It is not in the original. If it was, the first console.log wouldn't return the journals correctly, I will edit the post tho.

Comment: @Sigi I strongly recommend to switch to `HttpClient` and if you for some reason have to use Response object make sure that you are reading full response: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response